# How to create a custom color scale?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am trying to map a series of version strings to a series of RGB colors in hex form. Given a fixed set of version strings (eg `["1.1.2", "1.1.3", ...]`) and a couple of colors (`["#efebeb", "#4d4d4d", "#ff5d5d"]`) I want to create a scale that gives me an interpolated color for each version string.

I tried this:

```
const palette = scaleOrdinal().domain(props.sdkVersions).range(["#efebeb", "#4d4d4d", "#ff5d5d"]);
```

But this just alternates between the three colors:

[image: ordinal scale just rotates through set colors.]

I'm looking for smooth interpolation. When I try other scales typescript complains that it's the wrong types, or that they need to be numbers, etc. I'd rather not precalculate the list of colors since I won't know how many I'll need.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not clear from this question what the domain for your scale is. Would each major version have its own color range? You'd need to define the upper and lower bounds for each color. Can you provide an example of these inputs?

Comment: Sorry. The version strings are arbitrary and could be any strings (types of cats, days of the week, etc.) They're simply ordered, and there's N of them, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a fixed set of colours that you want to interpolate, no matter how big is the domain length, my solution involves using a linear scale to create the colours array, which you'll pass to the ordinal scale.

Therefore, you can create the linear scale with the 3 colours you want...

```
const linearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
  .range(["#efebeb", "#4d4d4d", "#ff5d5d"]);
```

... and then you populate the colours array, which you'll pass to the ordinal scale:

```
const colorArray = d3.range(data.length)
    .map(d => linearScale(d / (data.length - 1)));

const ordinalScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(colorArray);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's dynamic, working with any number of elements in the domain.

Here is a demo with just 3 elements (that is, in your case, three *versions*):

```js
const linearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
  .range(["#efebeb", "#4d4d4d", "#ff5d5d"]);
  
const data = "abc".split("");

const colorArray = d3.range(data.length).map(d=>linearScale(d/(data.length - 1)));

const ordinalScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain(data)
  .range(colorArray);
  
const divs = d3.select("body")
 .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d=>ordinalScale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now with 10 versions:

```js
const linearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
  .range(["#efebeb", "#4d4d4d", "#ff5d5d"]);
  
const data = "abcdefghij".split("");

const colorArray = d3.range(data.length).map(d=>linearScale(d/(data.length - 1)));

const ordinalScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain(data)
  .range(colorArray);
  
const divs = d3.select("body")
 .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d=>ordinalScale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And, finally, with 50 versions:

```js
const linearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
  .range(["#efebeb", "#4d4d4d", "#ff5d5d"]);
  
const data = d3.range(50);

const colorArray = d3.range(data.length).map(d=>linearScale(d/(data.length - 1)));

const ordinalScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain(data)
  .range(colorArray);
  
const divs = d3.select("body")
 .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d=>ordinalScale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly why I am looking for.